Some balls are taken randomly from group of balls? Is the probability dependent or independent?
My question is why does in the solution we treat events Xi as independent of each other. Like why is probability a/(a+b) in each case as if we choose the balls at random than they should depend on each other and that would result in a different probability for each event.
Question: A box contains '$a$' white balls, '$b$' black balls. '$c$' balls are drawn at random. Find the expected value of the number of white balls drawn.
Textbook solution:
$X_i = \begin{cases}1, & \textrm{if ith ball drawn is white} \\ 0, & \textrm{if ith ball drawn is black} \end{cases} $
$P(X_i = 0) = \frac{b}{a+b}$
$P(X_i = 1) = \frac{a}{a+b}$
$\therefore E(X_i) = \frac{a}{a+b}$
Consider S = $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{c} X_i $
$ \mathbb{E}(S) = \mathbb{E}(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{c} X_i) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{c} \mathbb{E}(X_i) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{c} \frac{a}{a+b} = \frac{ca}{a+b} $
This is the image associated with question: https://i.sstatic.net/ZLMUifOm.png

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

It's my first time posting question. Will take care next time.

Please delete the image and replace it with mathjax.

Hi! It might seem hard-hearted for us to insist that you take care this time, but because of the high volume on this site, it's in your own best interest to at least attempt to type in the question. If you refuse to at least attempt it, I suspect the question will get closed.

Ok if I do so will the question be reopened.

Essentially,
You are right. $X_i$'s are not independent of each other - $P(X_2 = 1 | X_1 = 1) = \frac{a-1}{a+b-1}$.
However, that doesn't matter for the expected value.
One argument is by the linearity of expectations - the book has expressed $S$ as a sum of indicator random variables, and linearity holds even in cases where the random variables are dependent. OK, so that tells us we can just add all the $\mathbb{E}(X_i)$'s, but it still begs the question - why is $ \mathbb{E}(X_1) = \mathbb{E}(X_2)?$
Consider that you're drawing the balls in the order $\{1,2...c\}$, with the same definition of $X_i$ as given in your question. Now, what is the probability of $X_2 = 1$?
By law of total probability,
$P(X_2 = 1) $
$ = P(X_2 = 1 \cap \  X_1 = 0) + P(X_2 = 1 \cap X_1 = 1)$
$ = P(X_1 = 0)P(X_2 = 1 | X_1 = 0) + P(X_1 = 1)P(X_2 = 1 | X_1 = 0)$
$ = \frac{b}{a+b}\frac{a}{a+b-1} + \frac{a}{a+b}\frac{a-1}{a+b-1}$
$ = \frac{ab + a^2 - a}{(a+b)(a+b-1)} = \frac{a(a+b-1)}{(a+b)(a+b-1)}$
$ = \frac{a}{a+b}$
So the unconditional probability of the 2nd ball being white is exactly the same as the first ball being white. Why is that? Well, because you have no information from the first draw at all - you didn't condition on anything. So $\mathbb{E}(X_1) = \mathbb{E}(X_2) = \frac{a}{a+b}$. By symmetry, this is true for all the $X_i$'s.
The intuition behind it is that you don't really have any information apart from what's in the group. You pick a ball but you don't observe it - do your probabilities for the next ball to be white change? As we've seen above, they don't.

Thanks that helped a lot...

Indeed, when $i\neq j$, the events of $\{X_i=1\}$ and $\{X_j=1\}$ are not independent. This means that their joint probability is not the product of their marginal probabilities.$$\Bbb P(X_2=i,X_4=j)\neq\Bbb P(X_i=1)\,\Bbb P(X_j=1)$$
However, those marginal probabilities are identical, for all supported $i,j$.  Every ball has the same chance to be in any particular position, and of the $a+b$ balls, $a$ are white.
$$\Bbb P(X_i=1)=\Bbb P(X_j=1) = \dfrac{a}{a+b}$$

What you are thinking of is that when given that ball $i$ is white, the conditional probability for ball $j$ to be white is: $$\Bbb P(X_j=1\mid X_i=1) = \dfrac{a-1}{a+b-1}$$

This dependency is not relevant to the problem, because Expectation is a Linear Operation on random variables.  We can show this for supported $i\neq j$, using the Law of Total Probability.
$$\small\begin{align}\Bbb E(X_i+X_j) &= 1\left(\Bbb P(X_i{\,=\,}1, X_j{\,=\,}0)+\Bbb P(X_i{\,=\,}0, X_j{\,=\,}1)\right)+2\,\Bbb P(X_i{\,=\,}1, X_j{\,=\,}1)\\&=\left(\Bbb P(X_i{\,=\,}1,X_j{\,=\,}0)+\Bbb P(X_i{\,=\,}1,X_j{\,=\,}1)\right)+\left(\Bbb P(X_i{\,=\,}1,X_j{\,=\,}1)+\Bbb P(X_i{\,=\,}0,X_j{\,=\,}1)\right)\\&=\Bbb P(X_i{\,=\,}1) +\Bbb P(X_j{\,=\,}1)\\&=\Bbb E(X_i)+\Bbb E(X_j)\end{align}$$
You can extend this for any selection of $c$ distinct positions, such as the first $c$ balls drawn:
$$\begin{align}\Bbb E(\sum_{i=1}^c X_i)&=\sum_{i=1}^c \Bbb P(X_i=1)\\&= \dfrac{ca}{a+b}\end{align}$$

To check the sanity of this, you should expect the count for white balls drawn when all balls are drawn to be the actual count for white balls.   And ... that it is.
$$\begin{align}\Bbb E(\sum_{i=1}^{a+b} X_i)&=\sum_{i=1}^{a+b} \Bbb P(X_i=1)\\&= \dfrac{(a+b)a}{a+b}\\&= a\end{align}$$
$\blacksquare$
